# Find the value of $\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{14i}{n}-5\right)\frac{4}{n}$ as an expression involving $n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, riemann-sum

> $\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{14i}{n}-5\right)\frac{4}{n}$ and where $\sum_{i=1}^n i=1+2+3+\cdots+n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

Not entirely sure if I did this correctly, but I basically plugged in $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ for $i$ and after some algebra and simplification I got $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{28n+8}{n}$

Comment: No, this is not correct: You can't just replace $i$ by $n(n + 1)/2$; after all, $i$ is an index that changes. What **is** true is that $\sum_{i = 1}^n i = \frac{n(n + 1)}{2}$. Your final answer should be a single expression, not a long sum.

Comment: I'm confused because the instructions tell me to use the formula for $i$ to assist in finding the value of the summation.

Comment: Yes, which is exactly what the formula $\sum_{i = 1}^n i = n(n + 1)/2$ *is doing*. You just replaced the index of summation with the value of the sum and left the sum in place.

Comment: @T.Bongers So if I leave $i$ in place I get $\frac{4}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}14i-5n$

Comment: omg.... $n$ is constant within the sum.... the only thing you need to sum is $\sum i$ and the constant sum everything else is to operate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your answer was incorrect is because you replaced $i$ with $\frac{n(n+1)}2$, but $i$ is not equal to that. The *sum* of all integers up to a number $n$ is equal to that. So the goal is to get $i$ in a position where it represents the sum of all integers up to $n$
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{14i}n-5\right)\frac4n=\frac4n\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{14}n \cdot i-\sum_{i=1}^n5\right)$$
$$=\frac4n\left(\frac{14}n\sum_{i=1}^ni-5n\right)=\frac4n\left(\frac{14}n \cdot \frac{n(n+1)}2-5n\right)$$
$$=\frac4n(2n+7)=\frac{8n+28}n$$
I probably went through more detail than needed, but hopefully it was effective. Notice how I didn't substitute anything for $\frac{n(n+1)}2$ until there was nothing else in the sum but $i$.